# How to document a single private attribute with Sphinx autodoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm using sphinx and the autodoc extension to automatically generate documentation from docstrings in my python modules.

I currently using the `automodule` directive to document all the public members of the module

```
.. automodule::
    :members:
```

My module also has a number of private attributes.  I'd like to include one of them in the documentation.

Is there a way to tell `automodule` to document all public members and also this one private member?  I've tried using the `:private-members:` option, but that includes all private members.  I've also tried manually specifying the private attribute, but then it doesn't document any of the public members.

```
.. automodule::
    :members: _PRIVATE_ATTR
```

I'd like to avoid having to manually list every single public member just to add this one private member.

Is there a way to do this with autodoc?

Comment: Could you give some context - *why* do you want to document one of the private members? Could that documentation live at the class/module level, or could you make it public, or ...?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Private members sometimes are useful in the documentation.  I can put the documentation for the private attr in the module docstring, but that means it would be documented differently from the rest of the attributes and classes (i.e. inline) and it will have inconsistent ordering in the rendered docs.  Considering :private-members: is an option, it doesn't seem like an unrealistic expectation to be able to document a subset of private members.  I shouldn't have to change the API just to get documentation to render correctly.

Comment: Well, it seems sphinx doesn't support it officially. Or you should be able to do `:private-members: _what_you_want`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  __builtin__ dunders and sunders are in python documentation. Same with C# and Java API's exposing internals that reflect on the externals...Was that a rhetorical question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I would expect to work (tested with Sphinx 1.8.3):

```
.. automodule:: yourmodule
   :members:
   :private-members: _PRIVATE_ATTR
```

But it does not quite work. If the `:private-members:` option is given, with or without arguments, all private members are included (provided that they have a docstring).

The `:special-members:` option takes arguments, so it is strange that `:private-members:` doesn't.

Instead you can use `autodata`:

```
.. automodule:: yourmodule
   :members:

.. autodata:: yourmodule._PRIVATE_ATTR
```

Here is a slightly different alternative with `autodata` "inside of" `automodule`:

```
.. automodule:: yourmodule
   :members:

   .. autodata:: _PRIVATE_ATTR
```

There is also an `autoattribute` directive but it does not work with module-level "data members". I have found that `autoattribute` can be used to document private *class attributes*, but [the documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) is not clear on the exact difference between `autodata` and `autoattribute`.

Comment: I think the difference is exactly how you said. `autodata` is for module members while `autoattribute` is for class members. [According the the sphinx docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute)
"For module data members and class attributes"